# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'to_sparse' - Simple audio recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, speech-recognition, attributeerror

Am trying to run the code from the link "https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio".
I have changed the tensorflow and keras version 1.14.0 and 2.2.4 respectively. Please help me to solve this error.

```
  **AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
    waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)**
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the tutorial is made for Tensorflow 2.x since that's the newest release. The code also looks a lot like TF2 since there is no Session to be compiled etc.

Comment: yes, they have used TF2,but I want to run this code in TF1.14 and keras 2.2.4. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: They are broadly not compatible, you would need to do a lot of working around to port the tutorial. Why do you insist to use an outdated and frankly clumsy version of the framework?